# Method for validating string input and returning double output

Tags: c#, validation, casting

I want to create a generic method to validate user input according to ceratin rules.

This is how I call the method and I get an error as string can't be double:

```
Console.Write("Input the price of the beverage : ");
string priceInput = Console.ReadLine();
double priceInputVal = ValidateBrand(priceInput);
```

This is the method that I'm calling:

```
private double ValidatePrice(string priceInput)
{
    bool success = true;
    double priceOutput; 

    do
    {
        bool result = Double.TryParse(priceInput, out priceOutput);
        if (result == false)
            Console.WriteLine("Please, write a valid number");
        else 
            success = false;
    } while (success);
    return priceOutput;
}
```

How can I solve this? I've already tested to cast the method, but that wasn't possible.

A thorough answer would be apprecietaed, I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is if the `priceInput` cannot be parsed to double, you will enter in an infinite loop. To avoid it, you can change your `ValidatePrice` method like that :

```
private double? ValidatePrice(string priceInput)
{
    double? priceOutput = default(double?);     
    Double.TryParse(priceInput, out priceOutput)
    return priceOutput;
}
```

And call it like that :

```
double? priceInputVal = null;
do
{
    Console.Write("Input the price of the beverage : ");
    priceInputVal = ValidateBrand(Console.ReadLine());
    if (priceInputVal == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, write a valid number");
    }
}
while (princeInputVal == null)
```

Comment: Your welcome. Can you please accept / up vote my answer then ? :)